# MySQL row into number of columns sum and payment option

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with records such as:

```
ID | Car_num | Service | Price | Payment
---+---------+---------+-------+-------+-
1  | 001     | shower  | 10    | card
2  | 002     | TV      |  5    | cash
3  | 001     | TV      |  5    | cash
```

How to write an SQL query to get the following output?

```
ID |Car_num | shower     | TV
---+--------+------------+---
1  | 001    | 10 (card)  | 5 (cash)
2  | 002    |            | 5 (cash)
```

Comment: Seriously, seriously consider handling this sort of thing in your application. Note that 'id' is surely meaningless in this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(t.id) as id, 
       t.car_num,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.service = 'shower' THEN t.price END) as shower,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.service = 'TV' THEN t.price END) as TV
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.car_num
```

If you want the columns to actually appear like `10 (card)` and not `10` (which is not recommended at all), then change it to this:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN t.service = 'shower' THEN concat(t.price,'(',t.payment,')') END) as shower,
MAX(CASE WHEN t.service = 'TV' THEN concat(t.price,'(',t.payment,')') END) as TV
```